# How to convert a uploaded CSV file to UTF-8 with ";" delimiter?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an importer that is supposed to upload a special file from a third-party program. The file is structured as follows:

```
TITLE,DESCRIPTION,PRICE,CURRENCY_CODE,QUANTITY,TAGS
"This is the file title","This is the file description and it can include line breaks

Size: 16x16
Weight: 1,5
for example here

more information.",12.99,USD,10,"Tag1,Tag2,Tag3"
"Next line","This is the file description and it can include line breaks

Size: 16x16
Weight: 1,5
for example here

more information.",12.99,USD,10,"Tag1,Tag2,Tag3"
"Next line","This is the file description and it can include line breaks

Size: 16x16
Weight: 1,5
for example here

more information.",12.99,USD,10,"Tag1,Tag2,Tag3"
```

I am trying to read this file line by line, which unfortunately does not work in JS.

```
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (evt) => {
        const file = evt.target.result.split('\r\n')
```

When I open the file in Numbers (Mac = Excel) and save via File > Export > CSV > Text encoding Unicode (UTF-8), the file is spit out as follows:

```
TITLE;DESCRIPTION;PRICE;CURRENCY_CODE;QUANTITY;TAGS
"This is the file title";"This is the file description and it can include line breaks

Size: 16x16
Weight: 1,5
for example here

more information.";12.99;USD;10;"Tag1;Tag2;Tag3"
"Next line";"This is the file description and it can include line breaks

Size: 16x16
Weight: 1,5
for example here

more information.";12.99;USD;10;"Tag1;Tag2;Tag3"
"Next line";"This is the file description and it can include line breaks

Size: 16x16
Weight: 1,5
for example here

more information.";12.99;USD;10;"Tag1;Tag2;Tag3"
```

I can work wonderfully with this file formatting. As i can see, all columns are now marked via `;` and the line break `evt.target.result.split('\r\n')` works as well.

Unfortunately, I cannot assume that my users will be able to convert this file.

Therefore, I would like to convert the file as Numbers does when uploading it.

How does this work via JavaScript new FileReader() ?

Comment: Why can't you read the file line by line?

Comment: In the downloaded version, the column separator is a ",". In the body text, however, there is also "," so that I cannot make a line break afterwards. I have tried several variants. Only when I resaved the file in Numbers and set the separator to ";" was the file easy to take apart.

Comment: Please don't post solutions inside the question. If you found an answer that was given useful, then please accept and/or upvote the answer that helped you

Comment: @DarkBee OK, I'll keep that in mind in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with it on two ways:

1. Frontend

Install `PapaParse`

```
npm install papaparse
```

Make the Browser automatically convert the `csv`:

```
let fileInput = document.getElementById('csv_file');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    Papa.parse(fileInput.files[0], {
        download: true,
        delimiter: ",",
        complete: function (results) {
            let csvRows = results.data;
            let newCsvStr = csvRows.map(e => e.join(';')).join('\n')
            console.log(newCsvStr)
        }
    });
});
```

2. Backend

Install `CsvWriter`

```
npm install --save csv-parser csv-writer
```

Convert the file before sending to the client on the Backend:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

const data = [];

fs.createReadStream('input.csv')
  .pipe(csv({ separator: ',' }))
  .on('data', (row) => {
    data.push(row);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    let csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
      path: 'output.csv',
      header: Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => ({id: key, title: key}))
    });

    csvWriter.writeRecords(data)
      .then(() => console.log('The CSV file was written successfully'));
  });
```

Comment: Happy to help, friend!